# Do I really need diodes to receive MIDI?

Tags: arduino, opto-isolator, esp8266, midi

[image]
[image]

All the schematics above use a diode before the receiving pin on the optocouplers. The problem was, I never able to find the exact same diode as the schematics.

[Before, I'm using H11L1, but it never worked.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400080/how-do-i-use-h11l1-correctly-to-receive-midi?noredirect=1#) Now I have plan to move to 6N138, but I'm afraid I'll meet another problem with this.

The end goal was receiving MIDI with either Arduino or ESP8266. Or is there any easier way?

Comment: A 1N4148 is a very common part. You could use DigiKey Part # 1N4148FS-ND.

Comment: @CharlesH I was trying to avoid buying online. finding one that sells locally returns nothing. I was trying to imagine what will happen if I don't use that.

Comment: Looks like a protection diode. If the input polarity is reversed then it prevents the opto-coupler LED from reverse breakdown

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan Any standard silicon signal diode or rectifier diode ought to work. A 1N400x, 1N4148, whatever. It shouldn't matter unless you use something really strange.

Comment: @CharlesH what is the worst case that can happen if I accidentally plugged in backwards? Also since MIDI has its own 5 pin connector ... Don't you think it would never happen?

Comment: Worst case is you fry the optocoupler. It's unlikely but it's not impossible. Accidental connections and shorts can be created during debugging and testing.

Comment: @Hearth the sellers said "this is the only diode we have." It is so small I can't even recognize whats written on it.

Comment: @CharlesH I'm okay with fried optocouplers. We have several here. So I can just ignore it, or use red LED like answer below?

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan If you don't have local sellers who can offer you the part you need, you might just have to give up on getting it locally. Transistor has a point, though; you could just use an LED. Or the base-emitter junction of a BJT, for that matter. Or base-collector, it doesn't matter for this purpose. PN junctions are everywhere.

Comment: You may need the diode to protect against ESD and surges, as this is an external connection.

Comment: FWIW I built a five way MIDI splitter about 8 years ago that does not have any protection diodes and it still works great. 6N137 optos, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The diode is there to protect the opto-LED in the event of a reverse polarity connection.

The [HF11L datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1793287.pdf) states that the absolute maximum reverse voltage for the emitter (meaning the IR emitter, the LED) is 6 V. Typically a 5 V supply would be used for the MIDI driver but it's worth being careful.

In your case pretty well any diode - including an LED would suffice. A red LED would limit the reverse voltage to < 2 V and would serve as an indication for reverse connection.

For further reading have a look at [Failure modes for LEDs](http://lednique.com/technology-basics/failure-modes-leds/) and [Opto-isolators - intro](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-isolators/) where I have written a little on the topic.

---

@CL raises a point that I rarely have to think about as it's not generally a problem in Ireland due to the damp climate: static. A static discharge of the wrong polarity can exceed the maximum reverse voltage by a factor of many thousand. The reverse diode protects the LED from this.

More reading:

- [ESD protection for LED systems](https://www.osram.com/media/resource/HIRES/333839/326035/esd-protection-led-systems.pdf) by Osram.
- Wikipedia's [List of LED failure modes - Stress related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LED_failure_modes#Stress-related).

Comment: Is that means I could replace that diode with just standard red LED?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Nice. I will accept your answer after trying it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would it be possible to connect a reverse signal? The diode protects against ESD.

Comment: @CL When you're talking about musicians, anything is possible,

Comment: @CL. Static too. I've added it in. Thanks for bringing it up. I would think that there have been plenty of cross-over DIN cables used over the years.

Comment: I just remembered that MIDI has TRS connector for really small instruments ... like LaunchPad Pro. Damn probably @stark was right.

Comment: @Transistor This makes me wonder something else. So basically the diodes (that I'll replace with red LED) protects the IR LED inside the optocouplers, by connecting it backwards. Don't you think it'll burn the red LED anytime soon?

Comment: Sorry, I do not appreciate your offensive language. Please delete that comment.

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan ESD does not have enough energy to burn a diode in the forward direction. And if you use TRS, you must protect the optocoupler LED against excessive current (see, e.g., https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/423360).

Comment: @Transistor done.

Comment: @Transistor sorry to make it personal, but I'm very stressed out that I'm not graduated yet because this optocoupler just decided it dont want to cooperate with me. :(

Comment: @CL I have no plan for TRS MIDI for now. Probably later. i don't want to add more thing that can broke my final project.  This already take too much time.

Comment: Just tested to run the circuit without diodes, and it work.